# Looking for the best way to provide a ViewModel on "Add new" View and just part of it / different one as its submit POST response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I'm developing a Web Application by using ASP.Net MVC 5. My model is something similar to:

```
Person
    - int ID
    - string FullName
    - int PersonTypeId

PersonType
    - Id
    - Name
    - Description
```

I'm working on the "create new Person" page. I have created a ViewModel with the following structure:

```
public class SampleAddViewModel
{
    public Person person;
    public SelectList personTypes; // Used to populate the DropDown element.
}
```

My controller's GET method (to simply display the page):

```
// GET: Add new person
public ActionResult Add()
{
    SampleAddViewModel savm  = new SampleAddViewModel();
    AddPersonViewModel.personTypes = new SelectList(PersonTypesEntity.GetAll(), "Id", "Name");

    return View(savm);
}
```

In my controller's POST method (to store the created person) I would expect to just receive the Person model, and not the entire ViewModel. But on the View page I think it is only possible to declare an @model razon line, which I think it must be @model SampleAddViewModel ...

Would it be possible to, in the POST Add entry, have something similar to the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Add([Bind(Include = "ID, Name, PersonTypeId")] Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Add(person);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    x <- //Should I re-create the ViewModel in here?
    return View(x);
}
```

Which would be the best way to address the problem? I'm also trying to avoid using ViewBag. Maybe the best way in fact is to re-send the entire ViewModel.

Comment: Why would you not want the view model (it contains the `Person` and allows you to return the view)?

Comment: It will post whatever fields you have within your form, it does not "post the viewmodel" and you can certainly have your post action take a person as a parameter, so long as you return a view model to the view.

Comment: You are right, you need to recreate your view model. Because you don't have values for SelectList.

Comment: why you don't use the SampleAddVieModel instead of person and use of TryUpdateModel(person) after declaring the person variable, and you don't need to re-create the view model in this case, but if you want to continue in what you are coding, yes you should return the view model of type SampleAddViewModel, so you should re-create it again, hope this will help you

Comment: @HadiHassan, You don't need `TryUpdateModel(person)` if you return the view model. `Person` is a property of the view model so its already bound and validated.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any errors on the server side on the POST method then yes, you'd want to send the ViewModel back to the view.

Since you are only sending a `Person` instance into the controller action and your View is expecting an instance of `SampleAddViewModel`, you should create an instance of one of these and pass it to the View; After all, you're going to need to repopulate the `personTypes` dropdown with data again.